# How to change Google Cloud app system time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to change the server time for my Google Cloud app. It is showing the time as 4:52 AM in my app when it should be showing 9:52 PM.

I have tried to SSH into the app and change it via 
`$ dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, but it doesn't seem to have persisted. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Cloud App Engine runtime's Time Zone environment variable is set to UTC, and can't be [changed](http://timezones.appspot.com/).You can change the time zone of a datetime in memory